# Can I remove the file after sending it to CUPS?

Tags: printing, cups

If I send a `ps-` or `pdf-file` to CUPS is it then stored in the queue as is or is it only a pointer to the file that is in the queue?

In other words: Could the file be removed from disk **after** it has been sent (and placed in the printer queue) but **before** it is actually printed?

If there is some load on the printer would this test produce any paper:

```
#!/bin/bash
uptime | mpage > uptime.ps
lpr uptime.ps
rm uptime.ps
```

Comment: Note that the question would belong more to Unix Stackexchange.

Comment: You can even pipe the data into lpr, such as this: `uptime | mpage | lpr`. Keep in mind if you are printing sensitive data, lpr stores the job somewhere and may even retain it after printing. I use CUPS at home and printed jobs are retained for 1 day by default, and can be reprinted from the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question for myself and just tested it.

```
lpr -P myprinter myfile.pdf && rm myfile.pdf
```

did print the 700K PDF file even though it was removed immediately after sending to print.

So I'd say the answer is "yes".